# How to store courses data safely and with the best way for easier adding/reading/removing - sequelize & NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

What is the best way to store courses the user enrolled in and his progress and every lesson he finished and the time he stopped on, is that will be as a column in user table with

```js
Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.ARRAY(...))
```

or what
or the best way is to enter data for the users who enrolled in a course in the course table

I wish that I can find the best way to do that safely and easier

I tried to do that in the user table but it seems be harder for store data, I want to store it immediatly without adding an array to another array

I hope that there is a simple way for all of that

User.model.js:

```js
const {Sequelize, DataTypes, UUIDV4} = require("sequelize");
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
   'Tafkeer',
   'root',
   'sb32986710*/Tafkeer',
    {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      dialect: 'mysql'
    }
  );

sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
   console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
}).catch((error) => {
   console.error('Unable to connect to the database: ', error);
});

const User = sequelize.define("tafkeers_users_table", {
   user_id: {
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    //defaultValue: uuidv4()
   },
   "firstName": {
     type: DataTypes.STRING,
     allowNull: false
   },
   secondName: {
     type: DataTypes.STRING,
     allowNull: false
   },
   email: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
   },
   password: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
   },
   curr_status: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
   },
   token: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
   },
   release_date: {
     type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
   },
   courses_enrolled_in_ids: {
     type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.TEXT)),
     allowNull: false,
     defaultValue: [['']]
   }
});

sequelize.sync().then(() => {
   console.log('Users table created successfully!');
}).catch((error) => {
   console.error('Unable to create table : ', error);
});
module.exports = User;
```

Course.model.js:

```js
const {Sequelize, DataTypes, UUIDV4} = require("sequelize");
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
   'Tafkeer',
   'root',
   'sb32986710*/Tafkeer',
    {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      dialect: 'mysql'
    }
  );

sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
   console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
}).catch((error) => {
   console.error('Unable to connect to the database: ', error);
});

const User = sequelize.define("tafkeers_courses_table", {
   user_id: {
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    //defaultValue: uuidv4()
   },
   firstName: {
     type: DataTypes.STRING,
     allowNull: false
   },
   secondName: {
     type: DataTypes.STRING,
     allowNull: false
   },
   email: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
   },
   curr_status: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
   },
   course_id: {
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
   },
   release_date: {
     type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
   },
   lessons: {
     type: Sequelize.ARRAY()
   },
});

sequelize.sync().then(() => {
   console.log('Users table created successfully!');
}).catch((error) => {
   console.error('Unable to create table : ', error);
});
module.exports = Course;
```

Comment: Are you planning on using JSON objects  versus using columns and rows?  Because I think MongoDB would be a better fit for that type of project.  Although MySQL can handle it, its being fleshed out with recent updates, but MongoDB has native support.  But if you are doing Rows and Columns, MySQL is the better choice.  

But what does your table structure look like?  Show us some code and tables so we can help.

Comment: Thanks, I added the code @easleyfixed

Comment: It looks like you are using JSON styled data, instead of Rows and Columns.  I would highly suggest you consider what i said about using MongoDB, its designed to store that data format natively, so probably takes less work to get it to be "correct" inside of MySQL.

Comment: I'm working better with MongoDB and I built a project by MongoDB, but this project is for someone not me, and he says that he wants the project built by MySQL not MongoDB, So this is the reason I switched to MySQL @easleyfixed

Comment: Ahh okay that makes sense, well I feel that, you don't often get to do what is best you get to do what someone wants you to do instead.  Well, good luck on your project!